# responsive filemanager with tinymc in laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, tinymce, file-manager, responsive-filemanager

I install responsive filemanager with tinymc in laravel.

When I click on img icon open dialog box for upload img but when I click on responsive file browser I see a dialog box with error not found.

How can I solve this error?

The link that want to open in dialog box :

```
js/ResponsiveFilemanager-master/filemanagerdialog.php?type=1&descending=false&sort_by=&lang=fa!
```

[image]

Comment: The `NotFoundHTTPException` is thrown when an HTTP request is being made to Laravel but there is not a route defined to catch it. Where is the file that contains the code that you're trying to fire?

Comment: Also, if you go to the root of the project in your command line and run the command `php artisan routes`, what does it output?

Answer (score 0):

check URL path is wrong /filemanagerdialog.php you have to add one slash / in tinymce config

```
your current settings without slash /
external_filemanager_path:js/ResponsiveFilemanager-master/filemanager

settings after slash /
external_filemanager_path:js/ResponsiveFilemanager-master/filemanager/
```

your calling url will be like this /filemanager/dialog.php